# viewPager and loadermanager callbacks

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-loadermanager

I have in my app a viewpager with 3 fragments. The middle fragment in the viewPager is fragment with a listview in it and it implements a loader.callbacks interface for a cursor loader.

The issue I have is that once I swipe left or right, the middle fragment stays in cache and "onLoadFinished" callback never gets called and therefore I never get new data from swapping the cursors.

Anyone has a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your data between swiping, then you have two options:

1. If you using `CursorLoader`: use `ContentResolver` to notify that data has changed. In this case your `Loader` will be updated automatically.
2. Call `restartLoader` inside fragment's `onResume` or `onStart`